# Mocha --require wait until migration

Tags: node.js, testing, mocha.js

I have a challenge to run a database migration before start my mocha suite test.

I am using the flag `--require` to load a `bootstrap.js` module that I have created and where I run the database migration.

The problem is that migration is an async function and as you know it returns immediately. So, there is any way to wait for the module to be ready until everything it's finished?

I can use some sync lib to convert migration to be synchronous but I would like to hear more strategies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a global `before` hook, like so:

```
import {runMigration} from './bootstrap';
before(done => {
    runMigration().then(done);
});

describe('some part of my suite', () => {
    /* ... */
```

If you write this hook in "root suite" - that is, outside any of your own `describe` blocks - it will run before all tests, regardless of which file you put this block in.

[Docs on root level hooks](https://mochajs.org/#root-level-hooks)

Note, that your hooks take too long, you might start getting an error like "Timeout of 2000ms exceeded", which can be solved by running mocha with `--timeout` flag - like `mocha --timeout 10000`

Comment: Thanks, I have created a `global-hooks.test.ts` file that contains a before and an after to initiliaze and clean my test resources! :)